# how to bypass nat firewall with torrent?

Tags: firewall, bittorrent, nat, p2p

I live in my parents hotel which has a nat firewall I can not access. The torrent protocol is not explicitly blocked, in fact downloading works seamlessly, but seeding does not work most of the time as the firewall does not open the port. Is there a way to bypass this restriction and get seeding to work normally?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to bypass this restriction and get seeding to work normally?

Not a good one.  You could use a [supernode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supernode_(networking))/proxy or try using a VPN service that caters to torrent users (VPN is a good idea anyway if you're doing anything of questionable legality).  Some of the VPN service providers have special port forwarding features.  However, both of these solutions will slow your transfers down.